# KStreams - Is aggregation and groupByKey guarantee a order?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

Imagine a situation where i have a topic with many of statuses, each in other log with the same key. Order of this statuses is known and always the same, like: create, pay, delivered etc.

So, if order is the same and known (and create status is first) in code below profileEvent.parcelEvent must always exist. But this is not happened, i'm getting null pointer exception in else if(paid) or else if(delivered) section. This is proof that created section does not execute first.

Question is why is this happening, assuming the correct order of messages?

```
                .groupByKey()
            .aggregate(
                    CustomerProfileEvent::new,
                    (key, value, profileEvent) -> {
                        if (created) {
                            Parcel parcel = value.getParcel();

                            return CustomerProfileEvent.newBuilder()
                                    .setEventTimestamp(value.getHeader().getTimestamp())
                                    .setParcelEvent(CustomerProfileParcelEvent.newBuilder()
                                            .setEventName(parcelCreated)
                                            .setParcelCode(parcel.getParcelCode().toString())
                                            .build())
                                    .build();
                        }else if(paid){
                            do some action on profileEvent.parcelEvent
                        }else if(deliverd){
                            do some action on profileEvent.parcelEvent
                        }

                        return profileEvent;
                    },
                    Materialized.as(Stores.persistentKeyValueStore(applicationConfig.getParcelEventAggregationTopicName()))
                            .withKeySerde((Serde) Serdes.String())
                            .withValueSerde(avroSerdeHelper.createCustomerProfileEventSerde())
                            .withCachingDisabled()
            );
```

Comment: Where  do `created`, `paid`, `deliverd` define?

Comment: If you do a `builder.stream(...).groupByKey(...)` the order should be guaranteed. However, if you do a operation after `stream(...)` and before `groupByKey()` that changed the key (eg, `map()`), a repartition topic will be created a order is not guaranteed any longer.

Comment: And how about aggregate? It's look like order is not provided when aggregating